# Need some clarification on benign prostatic hyperplasia (BPH)

Tags: urology, ct-scans, prostate, metastatic-cancer, enlarged-prostate-bph

My dad was diagnosed with [benign prostatic hyperplasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benign_prostatic_hyperplasia) (BPH) and recently underwent a CT scan. In the CT scan report, it is referred as "pedicle metastasis d9". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important that you and your dad see his doctor for an explanation of these results ASAP.  Reading CT results out of clinical context can lead to misunderstandings.  The doctor can analyze the CT results in the setting of your dad's clinical picture. Only he/she can explain the significance of the results, and what that means for your dad.

I assume you are asking this because you read that and were worried, so you tried to google it but found the results confusing. I can help clarify the individual words in your question and help guide your understanding, so that you are prepared for your conversation with his doctor.

This is NOT an explanation of the CT results. Only the doctor can do that for you.

Note that there are limitations to what a CT scan can tell you for certain.  A CT is not a perfect photograph, nor a tissue sample that you can say for certain is X Y or Z.  A radiologist analyzes the characteristics of abnormalities that he/she sees and makes recommendations of what it is - sometimes it is straightforward like a clear fracture in a bone, other times less clear like a shadow on a bone.  Again, you need the doctor to combine the CT results with everything else known about your father in order to say what he thinks is going on.

Definitions:

1. Pedicle means stalk and can be used for [several different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedicle).

Usually in human anatomy, pedicle will indicate the portion of the vertebrae (of the spinal column) that form the sides of the hole through which the spinal cord passes (see below in pink)[image: pedicle]

In surgical anatomy, there seems to be a neurovascular bundle referred to as the "prostatic pedicle."

[image]

2. "D9" and "T9" are both ways to designate the 9th Thoracic vertebra of the spinal column.  It is in the mid-back region.
3. A [metastasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastasis) is the spread of a cancer from the original site to another place in the body.  I have rarely heard metastasis used for anything other than cancer or similar processes.

The radiologist may be suggesting that it appears to be a metastasis on the spine.  But a CT scan can only suggest that something is a metastasis, it can't diagnose it for certain - that is why you need to see his doctor, who can interpret it along with your dad's clinical picture and tell you what it means.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice I'll see his doctor ASAP